# Looping through all sheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to loop through all the sheets within a workbook. I have the following code and it works totally fine; the only issue is that it only works if I launch the macro on the first sheet; if i do it in any other it just stops after the first loop.

```
 WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        'if sheet contains evdre
        Set c = ws1.Cells.Find("blabla")
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            'do things
        End If
     Next i
```

I am not sure if this issue is due to the fact that the macro should always be launched on the first sheet or if there is something wrong in the code.
Thanks for any help

EDIT
In the 'do sth part I am actually creating hidden sheets (hidden copy of the one that I am active at); can that make the count mess up? and thus only work in the first sheet

Comment: is it me or there is no part when the worksheet change in this code?

Comment: While iDevlop's answer is probably the more efficient way to do, if you change one line in your code, it will work for you: `Set ws1 = ThisWorbook.Sheets(I)` as long as in your `'do things` you reference `ws1` appropriately.

Comment: Yes, the problem in your code is just, that the ActiveSheet doesn't change, so it loops over the same Sheet multiple times. You could a) change it like Scott explainend or b) use a object-based loop like iDevlop explainend. b) is the better solution imho, because its easier to read and expand on.

Comment: and why if I launch the macro on the first sheet, it loops through all the sheets? I understand your reasoning but don't really know why it works properly then (on the first sheet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet, c as range
  for each ws in ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets
  Set c = ws.Cells.Find("blabla")
  If Not c Is Nothing Then
        'do things
  End If
```

Comment: when running an error prompts saying that  object doesn't support this property or method: `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook`

Comment: @iDevlop - forgot the Worksheets bit.  `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`  A WorkSheet is an item in the Worksheets collection.

Comment: I fixed the code (added .worksheets on second line) - Sorry